# Show MigraDoc/PdfSharp Document on screen

Tags: pdf, embed, migradoc

I want to use MigraDoc/PdfSharp to create and store PDF documents.

Is there a way to show these documents in an application on-screen? I'd like to show the print in my program rather than starting Acrobat Reader with the document name.

I considered storing the print using XPS instead of PDF, but then I'd need to way to convert XPS to PDF for mailing it to customers. And I don't want to save the same print in two formats for space reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MigraDoc can save files in its own format "MigraDoc DDL". You can preview MDDDL on the screen, create PDF or RTF from it or print it.
Disadvantage: images are not included in the MDDDL file (OTOH this can be an advantage as images can be shared between several documents).
You can ZIP document plus images for storage.

PDFsharp can create PDF files from XPS (but this is in a beta state and not fully operational).

Comment: So I could store the MigraDoc DDL and work from there. This is actually a nice idea. Are the images referenced by file name, or how would I need to store those?

Comment: PDF from XPS would be cool, too - even if it would only work for file created by MigraDoc itself. Is this still being actively developed? I had the feeling MigraDoc is a bit stale?

Comment: MGDDL references images by filename (fully qualified or relative). A new version of PDFsharp/MigraDoc is long overdue, but projects we get paid for didn't allow us to give MigraDoc the time we had planned for it.

Comment: Thanks for the information - and nonetheless a great library!

Comment: Btw, could mdddl be stored as a string/nvarchar in a database? It sure looks like it will not contain binary codes but text only.